# My Betta is laying on the bottom

Tags: fish, betta

My betta will swim once he sees us but when I glance at him he usually is laying at the bottom of his tank lately. I have a thee gallon tank with two nirite snails and a moss ball. I use a baister to take the water from the bottom and usually only do a 25% water change one every two weeks. He doesn't have any signs of illness on him other than he is staying on the bottom more than usual. He is eating normal. I usually only give him the most of three pellets a day. What do you think is going on?

Comment: Do you have any water pH/temperature readings?

Comment: This question is a lot like one I already answered. You can check it out here: [Is my betta dying/sick or just sleeping?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/is-my-betta-dying-sick-or-just-sleeping/11996#11996)

Answer (score -3):

Well, *Betta*'s fins are very long, flowy and sometimes it is hard for them to swim. I would add in Stress Coat, but I wouldn't worry so much if he seems normal otherwise.