# White patches/spots on my betta

Tags: diseases, betta, injury, infections

There are white patch/spot-like marks on my betta fish's gill and body, which were not there when I bought him from the store.

He is his usual active self and is eating properly. The spots seemed to have appeared after I have done water change. I use Seachem water conditioner to treat tap water that I use for the aquarium. The only decoration in his tank is an artificial plant and a tree log for hiding.

I have attached the photos. I am not sure whether he is ill or injured from decorations?

[image]

Comment: can you give some more details how large is the tank any filtation and have the tank been cycled properly https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm what are the water test showing amonia-nitrite-ph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my betta dying/sick or just sleeping?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/is-my-betta-dying-sick-or-just-sleeping)

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE :)

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxmCp.jpg) I have the same question. Today I noticed my betta fish has two white spots on top of his body but am unsure if it is a disease or if he hurt himself on some decoration. Please help if possible because am very worried. Have filter & heater is set to 78-80 degrees. ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Ebk.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the photo isn't conclusive the most common cause for "white spots" on a Betta is [Ich](https://bettafish.org/diseases/ich/), it's exceptionally common in Betta, and if left untreated can be fatal. Fortunately however it's relatively straightforward to treat.

From the link:

> 1. Move the betta to a hospital tank if there are other tank mates.
> 2. Increase the temperature slowly in your tank to 81-86 degrees fahrenheit for up to 10 days. Ich parasites prefer colder water, with colder temperatures leading to prolonged life cycles and increased reproduction rates.
> 3. Warmer water holds less oxygen, so consider adding an airstone. Increased oxygen can boost a betta fish’s immune system.
> 4. Follow the directions and administer the recommended medicine for treating Ich: (Rid Ich Plus) which contains malachite green and formalin. It is strong and highly effective.
> 5. Perform daily water cycling of 25-50% to reduce high medication levels and remove Ich trophonts and tomites.
> 6. Continue medication according to the directions and do not stop early. Ich protozoan are only vulnerable to medication two days out of their seven day life span, so continue even if they appear to be gone.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't look like Ich to me. In my experiences, ich generally seems to manifest in several places on the fish's body as small white granules rather than a single place in a larger white patch.

#### What's the mark then?

This looks like a missing scale or damaged scale which was probably caused by the wooden decoration log you talked about in your question. I have had frequent incidents where a fish (especially in a community) has been spooked by something and has caught themselves on drift wood or a decoration. They normally lose a scale but as long as your water quality is good, it should heal up no problem. Indeed, the only way to keep a fish in a pretty pristine condition is to keep them in bare aquariums with nothing in.

#### What to do next?

With anything like this, you'll want to test your water quality *just to check* everything is okay. If there is any ammonia or high levels of nitrate then @motosubatsu could be right. Ich is normally caused by poor water quality.

After testing your water and finding 0 ammonia, 0 nitrite and lowish nitrate, I would observe the fish for a few days. If this mark doesn't change or starts to fade, chances are it was just an injury from hitting a decoration and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

That's 100% not ich. I had a betta that started showing patches like that which eventually spread until it took over the entire body. I did a lot of research and the only thing I could find close to what it looked like pointed to a fungal infection. I did several salt dips as recommended with no success. During the 6 week period from the start to taking over his body, he did not lose his appetite surprisingly. The fish eventually perished, I assume as a result of this "disease". Maybe try a more agressive treatment labeled specifically for fungal infections, although I can't be sure that is what was in my case.

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. :)  Do you have any advice and links that could help Maha and her Betta?

Answer (score 0):

From the pics,it doesn't look like ich.Looking at the pic,I do see a light blotchy on his head,is this what you were describing? That spot looks as if it's an injury and should heal up.Like those have said,check yr water parameters  and best to keep a steady temp in the water.Keep an eye on the spots and see if it spreads or doesn't go away.Its a good sign if he is still active and eating.Ick makes a fish flash alot and makes the fish's breathing become labored..just monitor him as ya go

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. It sounds like you have quite a bit of experience with fish, do you?