# Skin Betta problem

Tags: health, fish, betta

[image]

Today I noticed my betta fish has two white spots on his body and I’m not sure what it could be if it’s cause by an injury from items in the tank or if he has a disease. Please help I’m very worried. I do have a filter in the tank & a heater that is set to 80 degrees.

I do also have tank mates. It is a 10 gallon tank. 
I have 2 Bala shark & 3 Cory catfish. Cory catfish are babies & bala sharks are small as well.

Comment: The picture if quite foggy, and there are white spots even where there is no betta. So I doubt that anyone will be able to understand where to look exactly. It might help everybody if you could take a better picture. It might help to add some extra artificial light, even temporarily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White patches/spots on my betta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23580/white-patches-spots-on-my-betta)